# How to check if the cronjob succeeded

Tags: shell, jenkins, cron

I am trying to add a cronjob for patching and I just wanted to know if it has been successful.
I have performed the following:

```
echo "0 0 * * * root yum -d 0 -y update > /dev/null 2>&1 && shutdown -r +1" >> /etc/cron.d/patch
```

Now, when I am going to the `/var/log/cron`, I think all the cron jobs should be listed there. Further, I cannot see any `/var/log/syslog`. I want to know if my script file (added as `patch` under `/etc/cron.d`) has been successful, how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Be very wary of applying patches without reading any of the associated notes that may be output and also be very wary about rebooting from a script, especially cron. If a patch requires manual intervention and you blindly apply it and reboot -- you may very well not have that host come back up. System updates are best applied manually and with Linux there is no need to reboot unless the kernel is updated. (all other processes, including `systemd` can be restarted on the fly)

Comment: @shellter I do not think the system cronjob will appear as entries when I do `crontab -l` as described https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296347/crontab-never-running-while-in-etc-cron-d [see the accepted answer]

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin what should be a better way/method to do this in an automated fashion?

Comment: Well -- you don't really want to automate updates. Depending on your distro, you may have to make manual changes to accommodate update (not often, but even once a year -- if you miss it and take a remote-administered machine down that's one too many). Generally updates take no more than 5 minutes. It's just one of the things you do every few days. If you are adminning a server, you may even purposely want to wait a few days to ensure the updates are good before updating your box. Quick example of manual changes [Archlinux](https://www.archlinux.org/), other distros are similar.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin any way in which I can check if the cronjob ran or not? I am trying to do `cat /dev/null` but getting nothing.

Comment: Well of course you get nothing. `/dev/null` is the bit-bucket, it is a stream connected to nowhere. Depending on your system, you will either have a system log, or systemd journal (and maybe a separate cron log). You can also set a `MAILTO` within your cron script if it runs as a user other than you so you are e-mailed any output when it runs (if you are the owner it emails you by default). There are also many different cron implementations `anacron`, `cronie`, `systemd timers`, etc.. and all have slightly different logging.

Answer (score 0):

> How to check if the cronjob succeeded

"Edits to a user's crontab and the cron jobs run are all logged by default to /var/log/syslog and [that's the first place to check if things are not running as you expect."](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto#Troubleshooting_and_Common_Problems)

```sh
$ awk "/clearme/ { print $1 }" /var/log/syslog
```

Also, set the shebang (the first line):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
```

And ensure you set absolute paths to executable. E.g. `datetime` should be set as `/usr/bin/datetime`

So in your case, the command could be:

`/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -y update > /dev/null 2>&1 && /usr/bin/shutdown -r +1" >> /etc/cron.d/patch`

Answer (score 0):

Cron mails any output on stdout or stderr. To know whether a cron job succeeded or not, make the output dependent on success: all good → no output. Something fishy → echo fishy.

Don't write a long command with such logic in the crontab--put it in a script and start that script from cron.